# 'show more fonts' option on gVim

Tags: windows, vim, fonts, gvim

In the `Select Font...` dialog of gVim, there's a link at the lower left that says `Show more fonts`. When I click it, I'm simply taken to the Fonts folder in Control Panel. How can I use that to set a font for gVim, if I wish to choose a font that is not among the short list in the dialog itself?

Answer (score 2):

Which fonts are available and what is used as a fallback for glyphs that are not contained in the selected font depends on the platform.

On Windows, currently **only fixed-width** fonts are supported; the font selector therefore only shows those. As you have already noticed, it also doesn't help to `:set guifont=` to them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the available usable fonts are already shown in the dialog and other fonts can't be used, what exactly is the purpose of the 'Show more fonts' link? Does it serve any useful purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`'guifont'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'guifont') option yourself, e.g. in your ~/.vim/vimrc or through Vim's command line.

For example:

```
let &guifont="DejaVu Sans Mono:h9"

set guifont=Consolas:h10
```

Note that using variable-width fonts in Vim is not going to work well. That's why the list filters them out.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was always puzzled by why the list was so short, this makes sense. Setting guifont to a variable-width font manually also seems to change nothing. By the way, is the 'Show more fonts' option useless then? Any idea what its intended purpose was?